# How to use an experimental command in nix?

Tags: nix

Like in this [tutorial](https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/our-first-derivation.html) I want to see the derivation.

```
ls /nix/store/*.drv | head -n 1 | nix show-derivation
```

> experimental Nix feature 'nix-command' is disabled; use '--extra-experimental-features nix-command' to override

I retry with the proposed change

```
ls /nix/store/*.drv | head -n 1 | nix show-derivation --extra-experimental-features nix-command
```

> error: unable to find a flake before encountering filesystem boundary at '/mnt'

Comment: Which version of nix are you running? Did you enable the `flakes` feature in a config file, such as `/etc/nix/nix.conf` (through configuration.nix for example) or `~/.config/nix/nix.conf`? You can check with `nix show-config | grep experimental`.

Comment: I've opened an issue to improve this https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/7475

Answer (score 4):

For permanent effect add following line to your configuration file "*~/.config/nix/nix.conf*"

```
experimental-features = nix-command
```

Create the conf file if it doesn't exist. You can append other experimental features like flakes etc.

Answer (score 1):

`nix show-derivation` expects its input as command line arguments.

Lacking any inputs, it seems to default to looking up a flake.

This would work, if it wasn't for `*.drv` producing too many results on my store:

```bash
$ nix show-derivation --extra-experimental-features nix-command $(ls /nix/store/*.drv | head -n 1)
bash: /run/current-system/sw/bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

If you have any `.drv` files, this works:

```
$ nix show-derivation --extra-experimental-features nix-command $(find /nix/store -maxdepth 1 -name '*.drv' | head -n 1)
```

Without any `.drv` files, `$(...)` produces no arguments, and that would be another way to get your error message.

Comment: Don't use `find` like `ls`. Use the `-exec` primary to execute `nix` instead: `find /nix/store -name '*.drv' -exec nix show-derivation --extra-experimental-features  nix-command {} +`.

Comment: Don't forget about the `head -n 1`! Your command will run `nix` for all `.drv`s. I'm pretty sure the `ls` part was meant to be illustrative, but if you really want to do this right, throw in `xargs` to batch the invocations and make it faster ;)

Comment: I'd rather avoid `head` for the same reasons I'd avoid reading from `ls` or `find`: file names can contain newlines. True, you can probably depend on *.drv files *not* to include new lines, and I suspect there are other places in Nix that assume single-line file names anyway. GNU `find` at least provides a `-quit` primary that will cause `find` to stop looking for files immediately after `-exec` does its thing. (`find ... -exec ... + -quit`).

Comment: Alright chepner, you win the internet today. Chep... - chapeau!